# How to use RDRAND intrinsics?

Tags: gcc, intrinsics, rdrand

I was looking at H.J. Lu's [PATCH: Update x86 rdrand intrinsics](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2010-12/msg01303.html). I can't tell if I should be using `_rdrand_u64`, `_rdrand64_step`, or if there are other function(s). There does not appear to be test cases written for them.

There also seems to be a lack of man pages (from Ubuntu 14, GCC 4.8.4):

```
$ man -k rdrand
rdrand: nothing appropriate.
```

How does one use the `RDRAND` intrinsics to generate, say, a block of 32 bytes?

---

A related question is [RDRAND and RDSEED intrinsics GCC and Intel C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29372893). But it does not tell me how to use them, or how to generate a block.

Comment: @Filip - Yes, BullRun has got a lot of negative criticism due to Snowden leaks (et al). In this case, I'm using a custom random number generator that extracts then expands entropy. There are multiple sources, so NSA backdoors will not cause a catastrophic generator failure.

Comment: [RDRAND and RDSEED intrinsics on various compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29372893) now does have an answer that shows how to use them.  But generally a system call like Linux `getentropy` instead of using `rdrand` directly, if/when that's possible.

Answer (score 6):

If you look at `<immintrin.h>` (mine is in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/`, Ubuntu 15.04 64bit), there are compatible (with MSVC, Intel CC) functions defined which pass data back to GCC built-ins

```
extern __inline int __attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
_rdrand64_step (unsigned long long *__P)
{
     return __builtin_ia32_rdrand64_step (__P);
}
```

for 64bit parameter and two others for 16 bit and 32bit parameters

```
_rdrand16_step (unsigned short *__P)
_rdrand32_step (unsigned int *__P)
```

You supposed to use those so your code would be compatible with MSVC, Intel CC and other compilers.

`_rdrand64_step` will fill 64-bit parameter (passed by pointer) with random bits, and return status. Ditto for 32bit and 16bit versions, [as documented in Intel's intrinsics guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=MMX,SSE_ALL,AVX_ALL,Other&ig_expand=796&text=rdrand), same for `rdseed`

UPDATE

> "These intrinsics generate random numbers of 16/32/64 bit wide random integers. The generated random value is written to the given memory location and the success status is returned: '1' if the hardware returned a valid random value, and '0' otherwise."

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/523864

UPDATE

Per @vy32 request, this is working for me. Well, my system got updated since original answer, so now it is Ubuntu 20.04.1, x64, GCC v9.3, compilation flags

```
gcc -m64 -mrdrnd -O3 a.c
```

`-march=ivybridge` or later implies `-mrdrnd`, but `-march=x86-64-v3` doesn't.  Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main() {
    unsigned long long result = 0ULL;

    // most real use-cases should loop until rc != 0
    int rc = _rdrand64_step (&result);

    printf("%i %llu", rc, result);

    return (rc != 1);
}
```

Concerning CF flag and "Ignoring this is a common implementation error that does not show up in testing, but does show up when you run the DRNG under load", I believe this is what built-in is doing. If you comment out printf and compile to assembler with -S flag, code will look like,

```
xorl    %eax, %eax
rdrand  %rax
movl    $1, %edx
...    
cmovc   %edx, %eax
```

which means that `%eax` is zeroed, `%edx` is set to 1 and then via `cmovc` `%edx` might be set to 0 if CF is raised. And this value is returned from function.

So I believe built-in is already dealing with carry flag in a proper way, and user should just check output of `_rdrandXX_step(ull*)` as described in manual.

Note that The file `immintrin.h` is an aggregate of all kinds of header files that define processor intrinsics. The *current* header that contains the RDRAND intrinsics is the `x86gprintrin.h` which you *should not* include.

---

Some CPUs (or microcode versions) have had broken RDRAND.  There [was a Zen 2 bug](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/10/how-a-months-old-amd-microcode-bug-destroyed-my-weekend/) where it always generated `0xffffffff`.  If you don't want to worry about the possibility of something like that happening again on future CPUs, it's probably best to get random bits from the OS (e.g. via Linux's `getentropy` system call).

Also note that recent microcode updates have crippled performance for `rdrand` / `rdseed`, making them very slow.  See the bottom of *[RDRAND and RDSEED intrinsics on various compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372893/rdrand-and-rdseed-intrinsics-on-various-compilers/72265912#72265912)*

Comment: What are the return values? How do we know if the function succeeded or failed?

Comment: GCC made a mess of this. Their use of [`unsigned long long`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38681146) is frustrating.

Comment: @vy32 what exactly are you asking for? Why do you need carryflag wrt random numbers?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux you should read the Intel application note. The DRNG can only deliver 800MB/s of randomness, and it clears the CF if no randomness is available. Ignoring this is a common implementation error that does not show up in testing, but does show up when you run the DRNG under load.

Comment: BTW, could you post an entire working example? I'm unable to get the `_rdrand64_step` to work in an actual program. Thanks!

Comment: @vy32 and another couple of sentences wrt Carry flag. I believe built-in is handing it properly

Comment: The builtin (and the intrinsic) return the CF result via the 0 or 1 return value, nothing needs to be "handled".  The `cmov` nonsense is to materialize the flag value as a 0 / 1 integer in a register (for printf).  This is a pretty inefficient approach, silly gcc/clang! 
 They're using the `0` integer output of RDRAND for the failure case.  It's also fully separate from the `rc != 1` return value clang materialize the normal way (xor-zero / rdrand / setc). https://godbolt.org/z/3e6aYb

Comment: @vyx32 is very appreciative!

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd not using eclipse myself, but https://www.badprog.com/eclipse-tips-n-tricks-adding-flags-to-the-gcc-compiler#:~:text=You%20may%20want%20to%20add,with%20the%20name%20Other%20flags.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux THX, In eclipse I've added `-mrdrnd`, instead of miscelaneous I've added it to Dialect.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - `immintrin.h` has always been an aggregate for as long as it's existing, which pulled in headers for all SSE versions as well as AVX.  (I think `immintrin.h` was new with AVX1, around 2010 or 2011; I don't know of any other header for a specific AVX version, but I wasn't doing SIMD development at the time.)  Your edit strangely says `immintrin.h` used to have *MMX* intrinsics; maybe you're thinking of `mmintrin.h` which has existed since before SSE1?  Intel's guide https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html still lists it for __m64 `_mm_add_pi8`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hmm, I looked in my Linux system and for version 9 of the gcc includes I see the rdrand instructions appear only in `immintrin.h` (I did a grep in all .h files). I looked up what `immintrin.h` stood for and it said that it initially contained just the MMX instructions. which where the first intrinsics used anyway, so that kind of makes sense. There seem to be various files, do note that the gcc header files might differ from Intel and Microsoft header files.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: My experience is primarily with GCC (and clang) headers.  But all the compilers mostly follow Intel's current documentation as far as if the guide says to include some header for some function, then including it *will* define that intrinsic.  At least for vector intrinsics; GCC and clang have some of their scalar intrinsics in `x86intrin.h`, and may not even have the same intrinsics in any header for old instructions like BSF (Intel documents `_bit_scan_forward`).  I'm curious where you found a claim that `immintrin.h` was ever only MMX, not SSE or AVX.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: The answers on [Header files for x86 SIMD intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11228855) haven't changed for a while, and are accurate AFAIK. And BTW, current GCC 12.2.1's `immintrin.h` starts with `#include <x86gprintrin.h>` then `#include <mmintrin.h>`, but I think `x86gprintrin.h` is a recent reorganization.

Comment: Yeah, for version 9 or 10; for 9 you get `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include$ grep -rn . -e 'rdrand'
./immintrin.h:161:_rdrand16_step (unsigned short *__P)
./immintrin.h:163:  return __builtin_ia32_rdrand16_step (__P);`  (etc.) as I've indicated.